# Jacobian matrix of Galilean transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, galilean-relativity

If we want to transform to another inertial frame of reference using [Galilean transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) in 4-dimensional space-time, what is the Jacobian matrix of Galilean transformation?

Comment: Hi Abdullah Almariah. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: To obtain the Jacobian, don't you just need to compute the partial derivates?

Comment: @jinawee would you write it? I mean as a matrix when the rotation matrix is $[R]$, translation is $A$ and the moving frame with velocity $U$

Comment: The problem is determining the general transformation as a function of $x,y,z,t$

Comment: The Galilean transformation is a property of 3-dimentional space. For 4-dimensional space-time use the Lorentz transform with the respective Jacobian matrix.